# Disable CDN through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, cdn, sharepoint-online

I built a React Typescript project in SharePoint.

I'm currently getting errors with how the CDN is serving up the content.

I want to disable CDN all together across all tenants.

Right now when I run:

```
Get-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Public
```

I get back `True`

I just want a way to disable CDN. I found this article here but I'm having trouble with the command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/remove-spotenantcdnorigin?view=sharepoint-ps

```
Remove-SPOTenantCdnOrigin -CdnType Public -OriginUrl sites/pubsite/siteassets/subfolder
```

I'm just not too sure what to put in the `sites/pubsite/siteassets/subfolder` section.

So all I'm trying to do is disable CDN on all tenants, I was following a tutorial and accidentally turned it on.

Comment: If you just want to disable CDN, run `Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Both -Enable:$false` against each tenant

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen so Tenant would be the site correct? lets say I have a site called `mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite` how do I disable it for this one?

Comment: That should be written up as an answer, not a comment, so it can be Accepted.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen your answer worked! Set it as a response so I can accept it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to disable the CDN option for a tenant without modifying the defined CDN providers, use `Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled`:

```
Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Both -Enable:$false
```